# Qt WebEngine with WebRTC for Embedded

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I've got a cross-compilation tool chain set up for building Qt apps and such to run on Raspberry Pi, using eglfs. This works with out issue.

I'm trying to compile the QtWebEngine module with WebRTC support, but can't determine why it refuses to enable WebRTC.

The output of running qmake in the qtwebengine directory:

```
brporter@fracked:~/raspi/qtwebengine$ ~/raspi/qt5/bin/qmake 

Running configuration tests...
Done running configuration tests.

Configure summary:

Qt WebEngine:
  Embedded build ......................... yes
  Pepper Plugins ......................... no
  Printing and PDF ....................... no
  Proprietary Codecs ..................... no
  Spellchecker ........................... yes
  WebRTC ................................. no
  Using system ninja ..................... no
  ALSA ................................... yes
  PulseAudio ............................. yes
  System libraries:
    re2 .................................. no
    ICU .................................. no
    libwebp and libwebpdemux ............. yes
    Opus ................................. no
    ffmpeg ............................... no

Qt is now configured for building. Just run 'make'.
```

Trying to dig through the qtwebengine mkspecs isn't turning up anything super obvious, but I'm probably missing something.

Comment: 3 years and no response. I am doomed indeed!!!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I'm struggling too at this.
I found out from [this documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-features.html) that you can use `-webengine-proprietary-codecs` to enable Proprietary codecs. It turns out that you can also use `-webengine-webrtc` to enable WebRTC... or at least that was what reported after configure. I haven't proceeded to compile Qt and test if it actually works.